# Read and replace the contents of a line using dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file below where I want to convert what is written on every fourth line into a number.

**sample.fastq**

```
@HISE
GGATCGCAATGGGTA
+
CC@!$%*&J#':AAA
@HISE
ATCGATCGATCGATA
+
()**D12EFHI@$;;
```

Each fourth line is a series of characters which each individually equate to a number (stored in a dictionary). I would like to convert each character into it’s corresponding number and then find the average of all those numbers on that line.

I have gotten as far as being able to display each of the characters individually but I’m pretty stunted as to how to replace the characters with their number and then subsequently go on further.

**script.py**

```
d = {
'!':0, '"':1, '#':2, '$':3, '%':4, '&':5, '\'':6, '(':7, ')':8,
'*':9, '+':10, ',':11, '-':12, '.':13, '/':14, '0':15,'1':16,
'2':17, '3':18, '4':19, '5':20, '6':21, '7':22, '8':23, '9':24,
':':25, ';':26, '<':27, '=':28, '>':29, '?':30, '@':31, 'A':32, 'B':33,
'C':34, 'D':35, 'E':36, 'F':37, 'G':38, 'H':39, 'I':40, 'J':41 }


with open('sample.fastq') as fin:
    for i in fin.readlines()[3::4]:
            for j in i:
                    print j
```

The output should be as below and stored in a new file.

**output.txt**

```
@HISE
GGATCGCAATGGGTA
+
19 #From 34 34 31 0 3 4 9 5 41 2 6 25 32 32 32
@HISE
ATCGATCGATCGATA
+
23 #From 7 8 9 9 35 16 17 36 37 39 40 31 3 26 26
```

Is what i’m proposing possible?

Comment: Your description is a little unclear as to how it goes from a genome segment to a number. Is there a biological reason why you are doing this?

Comment: Side note: that dictionary is actually unnecessary for converting a Phred quality score to a number. You could instead do `ord(j) - 33`. Unless I'm mistaken it will also be faster than a dictionary lookup. As a demonstration, please try `for c in '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFG': print c, ord(c) - 33`

Comment: @DylanLawrence I want to work out the quality score for each read for further analysis.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Are you suggesting to use that instead of the dictionary as the reference?

Comment: @lenhun: Yes, exactly. Please see my answer. ETA: I performed some tests and the dictionary approach is actually slightly faster! I have changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a for loop over the input file lines:

```
with open('sample.fastq') as fin, open('outfile.fastq', "w") as outf:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        if i % 4 == 3:  # only change every fourth line
            # don't forget to do line[:-1] to get rid of newline
            qualities = [d[ch] for ch in line[:-1]]
            # take the average quality score. Note that as in your example,
            # this truncates each to an integer
            average = sum(qualities) / len(qualities)
            # new version; average with \n at end
            line = str(average) + "\n"

        # write line (or new version thereof)
        outf.write(line)
```

This produces the output you requested:

```
@HISE
GGATCGCAATGGGTA
+
19
@HISE
ATCGATCGATCGATA
+
22
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, I don't really understand the `qualities = [ord(ch) - 33...` line. Could you help explain that please?

Comment: @lenhun 1) I've changed the line to use your dictionary `d`. 2) The `[d[ch] for ch in...`] is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). It's a way of turning each character in the line into a new value. 3) I did `line[:-1]` instead of `line` so it would chop off the last character of the line. The last character of the line is the "newline".

Comment: Ahh ok, that makes more sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`:

```
for i, line in enumerate(stdin, 1):
    line = line[:-1]  # Remove newline
    if i % 4 != 0:
        print(line)
        continue
    nums = [d[c] for c in line]
    print(sum(nums) / float(len(nums)))
```